# Setup a webserver as subpart of another server

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, domain

I have a website in a server, pointing to a domain, say example.com 
I want to create a new webserver (running in another port) for a second website. This is no problem.

The thing is that I need the second website to be reached in a url like example.com/second_website, So that I create the illusion that it is part of the first website.

The server is in windows. If I can get a general idea of what to look for, I would search for the details myself.
The reason why I am not just expanding the first website by simply adding the code of the new website in it is that we need to use other technologies for the new website.

Comment: Ok, I did not mention this earlier, so I'm adding it now. The code of the first website should not change whatsoever. Otherwise a redirect (as suggested by john-mahowald) would have been the most obvious solution. I can only play with the second website and networking rules / routes etc. But the original website must stay intact, both in code and other configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can define whatever additional hosts you want under your domain, say www2.example.com.

For user experience, note that people rarely type third level domain names these days. So to catch the traffic going to example.com  you could have a http redirect at appropriate places or links to the new site.

It may be simpler to have a hard cutover to the new site when completed.  You would not have to maintain two sites in parallel then.

Whatever you do, keep all URIs on your site pointing to the right place. Broken links infuriate users.

There are web site specific resources available including Webmasters Stack Exchange.